# Pointer to a type-defined structure

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

Okay so I have a following code that was previously written. This is for an assignment that I am doing and I cannot change these lines of code:

```
typedef struct
{
    int number;
    float average;

} B_PLAYER;


typedef struct
{
    char n[20];
    B_PLAYER k[12];

} TEAM;
```

And also two declared functions which look like this:

```
int result (TEAM t1, TEAM t2);
```

> ↑ exclude this function for now, this calculates the result of a match

```
TEAM* createTeam();
```

The code I must write is supposed to simulate a basketball match (multiple matches with 32 teams in total). Because the assignment is too long (and a bit complex), I will keep it short. So the the first part of the code above defines types named B_PLAYER and TEAM, which I understand. But my question is, why is the type name TEAM used as a function return type and what does the pointer to that type name mean(do):

`TEAM* createTeam();`  <------------ **This**

Keep in mind that, this function needs to create an address of a basketball team and return that same address. It must read values from the main() function(standard input). All 12 positions and all kit numbers must be filled.

I would gladly appreciate some feedback. If you need more information, I will write the whole assignment. :)

Comment: `why is the type name TEAM used as a function name` It's not used as a function name - it is the **return type** of your function. Your function name is `createTeam` and it returns type `TEAM*`. You should search for a tutorial on pointers in C (hint - your function should call `malloc` at some point to allocate memory for your returned value - and you should call `free` at another point in your program)

Comment: This sounds like stuff that should be explained in your course material. Did you ask your teacher?

Comment: `TEAM* createTeam();` simly means that `createTeam()` is a function that returns a pointer to an object of type `TEAM`

Comment: I think there is a typo in your question. `PLAYER k[12];` should be `B_PLAYER k[12];`?

Comment: @IanAbbot Yes, you're right. There is a typo in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @4386427 In the assignment it is written only what the function must do, I have posted it in my question. I' will regardless upload it again.

Comment: @klutt Appreciate the anwser, thank you. :)

Comment: @DanielKleinstein Okay, thank you very much for your anwser. :) And yes, I am supposed to dynamically allocate memory for teams in the main() function.

Comment: "why is the type name TEAM used as a function name" where do you see that? I don't see any function with the name `TEAM`

Comment: "and what does the pointer to that type name mean(do)" Do you know what a pointer-to-int (i.e. `int *`) mean/do ?

Comment: @klutt Unfortunately the teacher didn't explain it, nor did the assistants explain it. Assistants do not want to explain questions about an assignment if you haven't previously finished it (which sucks honestly).

Comment: @4386427 I meant the function return type. Made a bit of a mistake there when I was typing. As far as I remember the `int *` returns the value of that data type if I'm correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But my question is, why is the type name TEAM used as a function return type and what does the pointer to that type name mean(do):

> `TEAM* createTeam();` <------------ This

You are reading it wrong. TEAM is **not** used as a function return type!

`TEAM*` is to be read as "one thing" - you cant break into two like `TEAM` with one meaning and `*` with another meaning. It has to be read as `TEAM*` which means **a pointer to a TEAM object**.

So `TEAM* createTeam();` means that you must return **the value of a pointer to a TEAM object**. In short we just say: "return a pointer to a TEAM object" simply because it's implicit in C that functions always return values.

> So how can you get a TEAM object and return a pointer to it inside a function?

The answer is `malloc` (and friends). Like:

```
TEAM* createTeam()
{
    TEAM* team_ptr;                       // Create a pointer to a TEAM object
    team_ptr = malloc(sizeof *team_ptr);  // Allocate memory for a TEAM object and
                                          // assign the address of that memory
                                          // to the pointer
    if (team_ptr == NULL) exit(1);        // Error checking
    return team_ptr;                      // Return (the value of) the pointer to the TEAM object
}
```

The in e.g. `main` you can do:

```
TEAM* teamA = createTeam();
TEAM* teamB = createTeam();
```

Now you have 2 pointers to differen TEAM objects.

But wait... they have no values. No, you need to add some code to read values that you want to assign to the TEAM objects. Maybe like this:

```
TEAM* createTeam()
{
    TEAM* team_ptr;
    team_ptr = malloc(sizeof *team_ptr);
    if (team_ptr == NULL) exit(1);

    // Read team name
    fgets(team_ptr->n, sizeof team_ptr->n, stdin);
    size_t len = strlen(team_ptr->n);
    if (len > 0) team_ptr->n[len-1] = '\0';  // remove newline if present

    // Read the players
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        team_ptr->k[i].number = 42;    // Add your own code to get it from stdin
        team_ptr->k[i].average = 42.0; // Add your own code to get it from stdin
    }
    return team_ptr;
}
```

tip: fgets and sscanf could be useful for the "missing" code.

So now you can do like this in e.g. `main` :

```
TEAM* teamA = createTeam();
TEAM* teamB = createTeam();
printf("Next match will be %s playing %s\n", teamA->n, teamB->n);
printf("Player number %d at team %s has average %f\n", teamA->k[0].number, teamA->n, teamA->k[0].average);
```

And once you are done with the teams you do:

```
free(teamA);
free(teamB);
```

Comment: You have helped me very much sir, thank you! Would you mind if I send you the assignment? Your anwser has been of great help, and I think we'll be on the same page if you know exactly what needs to be done in this certain task. :)

Answer (score 1):

`TEAM* createTeam();` declares a function which returns a pointer to a `TEAM` structure variable allocated elsewhere. Meaning somewhere inside there's likely code like this:

```
TEAM* t = malloc(sizeof *t);
...
return t;
```

As a side note, empty parenthesis is obsolete style in C. You should be writing `TEAM* createTeam(void)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the anwser! I know that empty parenthesis is obsolete, yet we need to stick to that type of declaration because it is fixed and we must not change it.

I could post the entire assignment, maybe that way it will be easier to understand what needs to be done. Appreciate your feedback. :)